# is this sentence right? is it a slang? or is it wrong?

Tags: slang

If I want to say I am good at something but not very good can I say "I am about good" does this phrase considered slang.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean, "I am quite good" or "I am moderately good."?

Comment: "I am about good" would be confusing to many listeners.  You might say "I'm fairly good" or "I'm pretty good at framifying whatsits".

Comment: Along with @HotLicks suggestions there's also "sort of good" (in speech *sorta*), "okay", "adequate" which are all a little bit "less good" than his suggestions.

Comment: And there's always "I get along."

Answer (score 1):

This wouldn't be standard, and I wouldn't use it formally. However, in response to the question "Are you good?", you could say "I am *about* good", with a lot of emphasis on the word *about*. However, "about" is an unnatural modifier for "good", because it "about" usually refers to a specific quantity, time, or place — which "good" *isn't*.

In American English, I think the normal response, if you want to say that you're good, but not perfect, would be "I am [pretty good](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26335/what-is-the-precise-meaning-of-pretty-good)."

Comment: mattdm, I like this answer enough that I'd like to see you add some examples: It works for quantity (Do you have any money? *I'm **about** out), time (Are you finished? *I'm **about** done), and place (Are you home yet?  *I'm just **about** there.)  But it's not idiomatic with qualities:  **about** good, **about healthy**, **about tall** -- they don't work.  You have prior permission to use my examples if you wish.