# "Pretty positive" vs "very positive"

Tags: meaning, connotation

I'm overthinking here a bit after I heard back from my recruiter regarding my interview performance. One recruiter from one company said the feedback was "pretty positive" and another said "very positive." Now I'm wondering whether "pretty" is not as good as "very." In my daily usage of the words, I think the latter is more positive than the former, so "very" generally sounds better to me than "pretty." Is this the general interpretation of these qualifiers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the precise meaning of "Pretty Good"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26335/what-is-the-precise-meaning-of-pretty-good)